# ¿Existe alguna forma de saber si el servicio de correo smtp esta arriba?

Tags: ubuntu, smtp

A veces se me bloquea el servicio de correos y no me doy cuenta cuando ya es tarde, tengo a los usuarios encima de mi, pidiendo que les resuelva inmediatamente ( cosas de usuario ), hay alguna forma de saber que el servicio de correos está arriba ejecutándose, por ejemplo, para saber si tengo el servicio de Internet le doy en la linea de comando:

```
$ sudo systemctl status network-manager.service
```

y me responde si está activo  o no: active ***(running)***

¿Existe algo que pueda consultar con el comando **systemctl**.?

Sistema Operativo es : **Lubuntu 18.04**

tengo instalado **mailutils** y **ssmtp**

De antemano muchas gracias por su gestión.

Comment: Podrías hacer un script bash que ejecute un cron que lance ese comando de manera indefinida por ejemplo cada 5 minutos, si está activo no hace nada y si está inactivo que te mande algún tipo de notificación

Comment: Tamblien puede utilizar Nagios3 para monitar los servicios.  Es un poco complejo pero puede monitar más de correo si ud.necesita.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con el comando `ps` y el comando `grep`
**ejemplo:**

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep smtp
```

- el comando `ps` es para ver los procesos
- los flag `-e` es para seleccionar todos `-f` muestra en lista
- el comando `grep` es un buscador de texto
- el flag `-v` es para omitir esa palabra `en este caso porque se crea
  un pid para la busqueda por parte de grep con la palabra a buscar`
- el simbolo `|` es una redirecion atrapa lo que se ejecuta antes y se
  lo pasa al siguinte comando

Answer (score 0):

Podes fijarte si el puerto está escuchando conexiones:

```
netstat --listening -t
```

--listening: puertos escuchando conexiones.
-t: protocolo tcp

Ahi fijate el o los puertos que tengas configrados con smpt.
Los puertos comunmente usados pueden ser:  25, 465, 587 o 2525.

Answer (score 0):

otra opcion es hacer un telnet al host del servicio y el puerto de correo. Suponiendo que lo tienes en un equipo local y el puerto que tienes configurado es el 25, podrias hacer:

```
telnet localhost 25
```

Si te abre una conexion, entonces el servicio esta levantado.